# How to save (custome) Firestore Document name no't auto generated From firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

### I have this DOCUMENTS names

```
tdQrydxFvlyKFXpwwecqUbF
tdQrydeXpcqUbqweqwweqwF
tdQrydxFeXpcqqweqwwwUbe
tdQrydxFeqwewqwepcqUbF2
```

### And I want this

```
my_customer_id_1
my_customer_id_2
my_customer_id_3
my_customer_id_4
```

#### My code to push new docs in Collection

```
       const _data = {
          email: 'someemail',
          uid:'some_uid',
          first_name: 'some name',
          last_name: 'some_last_name',
          favorites: [],
          shopping_cart: [],
          history: [],
          settings: {},
          purchases: [],
          created: 14753652226,
          updated: 14753652226
        }

        this.add_new_user(_data).then( snap => {  <=== this push documents with random names and i don wont that
          console.log(snap);
        }).catch ( error => {
          console.log(error);
        });





 add_new_user(data:CustomerEntity, uid:String){
    this.customers_collection = this.afs.collection('customers/' + uid);
    return this.customers_collection.add(data);
  }
```

this give this output when i get buck the data

```
  tdQrydxFvlyKFXpwwecqUbF: {  <-- I dont want random Key ,I want to manualy set this key
     email: 'someemail',
      uid:'some_uid',
      first_name: 'some name',
      last_name: 'some_last_name',
      favorites: [],
      shopping_cart: [],
      history: [],
      settings: {},
      purchases: [],
      created: 14753652226,
      updated: 14753652226
    }
```

Comment: what `this.add_new_user(_data)` do? post the code.

Comment: The code is to big to show you the rest. of code. read the title again

Comment: What `this.add_new_user(_data)` does is probably the only thing we need to know since that's where you seem to save the data.

Comment: add_new_user(data:CustomerEntity, uid:String){
    this.customers_collection = this.afs.collection('customers/' + uid);
    return this.customers_collection.add(data);
  }

Comment: I want to set manualy the name of the path

Comment: I want to save in customers a doucument with key that gona be the same like the USER ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I got this right from your comments what you need is:

in your code you aren't actually sending the uid to your add_new_user method? So, something like:

```
this.add_new_user(_data, _data.uid)
```

and then your add_new_user method

```
add_new_user(data:CustomerEntity, uid:String)
{ 
this.customers_collection = this.afs.collection('customers').doc(uid); 
return this.customers_collection.add(data); 
}
```

or leave

```
this.add_new_user(_data)
```

like it is, and do

```
 add_new_user(data:CustomerEntity)
    { 
    this.customers_collection = this.afs.collection('customers').doc(data.uid); 
    return this.customers_collection.add(data); 
    }
```

if that works.

Comment: You see this is what i want. Thanx Bro i find the solution but i want to help you for your help